# Store the output of a query which returns multiple rows in a single variable in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

```
Declare 
v_cardRecord card%ROWTYPE;
v_cardRecords IS TABLE OF card%ROWTYPE;
i BINARY_INTEGER;
Begin
select nt.name, nd.name, ct.name, ps.name, count(c.cardid) BULK COLLECT INTO v_cardRecords
from cardtype ct, card c, node n, nodetype nt, nodedef nd, provisionstatus ps
where ct.name in ('SRA AMP', 'XLA AMP', 'SAM', 'ESAM')
and ct.cardtypeid = c.card2cardtype
and c.card2node = n.nodeid
and n.node2nodetype = nt.nodetypeid
and n.node2nodedef = nd.nodedefid
and c.card2provisionstatus = ps.provisionstatusid
group by nt.name, nd.name, ct.name, ps.name;
```

Error"PLS-00103, encountered "IS" when expected one of the following.

2- After that, I want to store the v_cardRecords in another table.

How should I do?

Comment: I'm guessing that you really intended to declare a type `type typ_cardRecords is table of card%rowtype` and then declare a local variable of that type `v_cardRecords typ_cardRecords`.  If you're just going to take that data and write it to a different table, though, you'd be better off simply writing a set-based `insert` statement.

Comment: Could you explain why do you want to store it in a single variable ? A side note: this code is unlikely to work, since a result of the query consist of 2 columns coming from `nodetype` table, one column from `cardtype` table, one column from `provisionstatus` table and one column of `NUMBER` datatype. The record (that is - a structure of `card` table) **must** have the same number of columns as the query, and types of all corresponding columns **must** match, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: @kordirko I do want to store it in a single variable because I want to use that for iterating through the table. The variable holds the of output of the query. Open to other suggestions..

Comment: Depends on what `iterating through the table` really means - I gues that you want to do some operations on retrieved records - some calculations ? Then maybe insert, update, delete ? Or pass the result to some client ? Some web or thin application, save to disk as a file, in Excel/SCSV file or so ? In most cases a pure SQL is the best option, in some cases a cursos can be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want select data from several tables and then insert the results into another, then in terms of efficiency your best approach is

```
INSERT INTO <table_name>
(<column>
,<column>
)
SELECT
FROM
;
```

However if you need to transform the data with procedural logic then bulk processing is certainly the way to go.  Your approach doesn't work for a number of reasons :

1. you are bulk collecting into a record structure that does not match
   your query
2. your query contains several columns with the same alias
3. syntax errors in your bulk collect

The following is closer to what you want :

```
DECLARE 

  CURSOR C_get_cards
  IS
    SELECT 
     nt.name     nt_name
    ,nd.name     nd_name
    ,ct.name     ct_name
    ,ps.name     ps_name
    ,count(c.cardid) 
    FROM cardtype ct, card c, node n, nodetype nt, nodedef nd, provisionstatus ps
    WHERE ct.name in ('SRA AMP', 'XLA AMP', 'SAM', 'ESAM')
    AND ct.cardtypeid = c.card2cardtype
    AND c.card2node = n.nodeid
    AND n.node2nodetype = nt.nodetypeid
    AND n.node2nodedef = nd.nodedefid
    AND c.card2provisionstatus = ps.provisionstatusid
    GROUP by nt.name, nd.name, ct.name, ps.name
  ;
  TYPE cards_TAB_TYPE IS TABLE OF C_get_cards%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER ;
  T_card_details              cards_TAB_TYPE ;

BEGIN
  OPEN C_get_cards ;

  LOOP

    FETCH C_get_cards
      BULK COLLECT INTO T_card_details
      LIMIT 250
    ;

    FOR i IN 1..T_card_details.COUNT LOOP
      NULL ; 
      -- <transform / work on data here>  
    END LOOP ;

    FORALL i IN T_card_details.FIRST..T_card_details.LAST 
      INSERT INTO table_name
       (column1
       ,column2
       )
       VALUES
       (T_card_details(i).nt_name 
       ,T_card_details(i).nd_name 
       )
    ;

    EXIT WHEN T_card_details.COUNT = 0 ;

  END LOOP ;
END ;
```

Comment: Here Is T_card_details is a Tabletype variable?  So if it is, then I want to use T_card_details as a table column and store it in a table. e.g column A, column B, column C and my column C has value as T_card_details. Thus I want to use an iterator in this table after. Hope I could make you understand.

Comment: In order for you to do that I think you may need to define an Object.  I'm afraid I have to run and catch a plane but the following document might help you https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjint.htm